# Array manipulation skip in python

Tags: python, arrays

Say I have an Array A which is 8 x 2. I want to manipulate this array into another Array B (2 x 8). For the first row of the new array B, however I want to sample different areas of the Array A. i.e skip rows of Array A.

For example Array `A = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]..... [15,16]]`. I want the first line of Array B to be `B = [[1,2,3,4,13,14,15,16]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.chain`.

```
In [18]: from itertools import chain

In [25]: B = []

In [26]: B.append(list(list(chain.from_iterable(A))))

In [27]: B
Out[27]: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: Can you explain this please. When I run the code that you have posted above it doesnt skip rows in the A array.                                                           >>> B
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]

Comment: Use indexing if you want to skip the rows.